# How to convert excel(xls) file to html and add sorting and filtering

Tags: html, sorting, filtering, xls

Below code is working for excel to html conversion and partial sorting.

I want when any cells in the header(or first row) is clicked the entire table should get sorted 
based on that column(either ascending or descending).

Note:Below Code is tested with any excel input file and supporting settings for activex in internet options in IE9.

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Test</TITLE>    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>

    <STYLE TYPE="text/css">body div * { font-family: Verdana; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10px; } body { background-color: #FFEEFF; } .tableContainer table { border: 0px solid #000000; } .tblHeader { font-weight: bold; text-align: center; background-color: #FFAAEE; color: black; } .oddRow, .evenRow { vertical-align: top; } .tblHeader td, .oddRow td, .evenRow td { border-left: 2px solid #FFFFFF; border-bottom: 0px solid #000000; border-top: 0px solid #000000;} .lastCol { border-right: 0px solid #000000; } .oddRow { background-color: #abcdef; } .evenRow { background-color: #f0f0f0; }</STYLE>
    <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

        function _ge(id) {

                return document.getElementById(id);
        }

        function sortTable(){
            var tbl = document.getElementById("tblExcel2Html").tBodies[0];
            var store = [];
            //alert(tbl.rows.length);
            for(var i=0, len=tbl.rows.length; i<len; i++){
                var row = tbl.rows[i];
                //alert(row.cells[1].innerText);
                var sortnr = parseFloat(row.cells[1].textContent || row.cells[1].innerText);
                if(!isNaN(sortnr)){
                    alert(store.push([sortnr, row]));
                    //store.push([sortnr, row]);
                }
            }
            store.sort(function(x,y){
                //alert(x[0] - y[0]);
                return x[0] - y[0];
            });
            //alert(store.length);
            for(var i=0, len=store.length; i<len; i++){
                alert(tbl.appendChild(store[i][1]));
              //alert(tbl.appendChild(store[i][1]));
            }

            //alert(store);
            store = null;
        }

        function convert2HTML() {

            var ex;
            try {
                ex = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
            }
            catch (e)
            {
                alert('Your browser does not support the Activex object.\nPlease switch to Internet Explorer.');
                return false;
            }

            //alert(arraytext);

            //var ef = ex.Workbooks.Open("D:\\JS_HTML5\\Vin\\Test.xlsx");

            var ef = ex.Workbooks.Open("D:\\JS_HTML5\\docs\\filter4\\tests\\Test.xlsx");

            var es = ef.Worksheets(1);

            var colsCount = ef.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count;
            //alert(colsCount);
            var rowsCount = ef.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count;
            //alert(rowsCount);

            var rStart = parseInt(1,10);
            var cStart = parseInt(1,10);

            var cEnd = parseInt(colsCount,10);
            var rEnd = parseInt(rowsCount,10);

              var oc = _ge('tableContainer');

            oc.innerHTML = '';
            var tbl = document.createElement('TABLE');
            tbl.id = 'tblExcel2Html';

            tbl.border = '10';
            tbl.cellPadding = '4';
            tbl.cellSpacing = '0';

            oc.appendChild(tbl);
            var i,j,row,col,r,c;

            for(i = rStart, r = 0; i <= rEnd; i++,r++) {

                row = tbl.insertRow(r);
                row.className = (i == rStart) ? 'tblHeader' : (i % 2 == 0) ? 'evenRow' : 'oddRow';

                for(j = cStart, c = 0; j <= cEnd; j++,c++) {

                    col = row.insertCell(c);
                    col.className = (j == cEnd) ? 'lastCol' : '';
                    col.innerHTML = es.Cells(i,j).value || ' ';

                }
            }
            ex.ActiveWorkbook.Close(true);
            ex.Application.Quit();
            ex = null;

            sortTable();
        }

    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload = "convert2HTML()">
<h2>Test</h2>
<hr><br>

<!--     <td colspan="6" align="CENTER"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Convert to HTML" ONCLICK="convert2HTML()"></td> -->

<div id="tableContainer"></div>
<div id="tblExcel2Html"></div>
<footer>
    <br>
             <center>    &copy;Initial Draft V0.1     </center>
</footer>
<a href="Home.html" >Home</a>
</BODY>
```

Basically i want to convert excel to html with sorting and filtering support.

Thanks in Advance
Vinoth.S

Comment: What is your question? what doesn't work? What have you tried?

Comment: Basically i want to convert excel to html with sorting and filtering support.With the above i can successfully convert excel to html but i am stuck up in sorting and filtering.

Comment: But what have you tried? What is the error message you are getting? where are you stuck? Have you looked at using any plugins to handle the sorting (Jquery table sorter for example)

Answer (score 0):

The creation of the object by calling

```
ex = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
```

works only in windows systems with Excel installed. I suggest you to use [jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com) as javascript data-viewer and a php library like [phpexcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) that parse the excel and return raw data.

Comment: Any solution/answers?